# iReport external font

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to use external font in PDF document. I have no problem with using it in iReport after installing it via Settings -> Fonts -> Install new font.

The problem that when I export the new font as extension and adding that jar to java project's classpath - the PDF couldn't be generated and fails with

`JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial Custom' is not available to the JVM exception`

What I am doing wrong?
Thank you

UPD#1:

jasperreports_extensions.properties

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.ireportfamily1329192368547=fonts/fontsfamily1329192368547.xml
```

fontsfamily1329192368547.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>

   <fontFamily name="Arial Custom">
       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/arial.ttf]]></normal>
       <bold><![CDATA[fonts/arialbd.ttf]]></bold>
       <italic><![CDATA[fonts/ariali.ttf]]></italic>
       <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/arialbi.ttf]]></boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
       <locales>
               <locale><![CDATA[en_US]]></locale>
       </locales>
   </fontFamily>    

</fontFamilies>
```

fonts directory includes all ttf files. I just added that jar to classpath.

Comment: Can you post the xml file with font definition and the snippet of the jrxml file where this font is used?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. See updates in question

Comment: Alex asked for a piece of the .jrxml. You have not posted that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my working sample.

The font definition file (I dig it from the font's jar file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
   <fontFamily name="Arial">
       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/arial.ttf]]></normal>
       <bold><![CDATA[fonts/arialbd.ttf]]></bold>
       <italic><![CDATA[fonts/ariali.ttf]]></italic>
       <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/arialbi.ttf]]></boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[false]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

The jar file is in the application's classpath.

And here is my java code:

```java
String defaultPDFFont = "Arial";

JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font", "true");
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name", defaultPDFFont);

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);
```

I set the ***`net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font`*** property to prevent the error you have (`JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial Custom' is not available to the JVM exception`) in case the font is missing. And I set the ***`net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name`*** property for determine the font that will be used in the resulting pdf file.

You can read info about this properties: [net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font) and [net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name).

The resulting pdf file is using this font (`Arial` in this sample).

Comment: Thanks! I found where my problem was - I installed font as embedded.

Comment: JRProperties.setProperty depricated 
need:
DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font","true");