# Using Chinese characters using Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How to use chinese characters in *JasperReports* using *Java*. Presently I am using below code.
 This works fine for HTML, DOC but it is not working for PDF.

```
<textField>
   <reportElement x="49" y="0" width="277" height="52" uuid="a17f1430-f415-4eba-9769-b02ca05731a8"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="STSong-Light" pdfFontName="STSong-Light" pdfEncoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["入　学　許　可　証"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

I have also tried using  *iReport Designer 5.5.0* but still result is same.

Comment: What's going wrong? Is the text showing? I'm guessing this is going to be an encoding issue. What's the encoding of your XML document? (eg `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`). What editor are you using to edit the file? (the editor may have it's own encoding)

Comment: Probably a font missing from the pdf generation software

Comment: @RaviShekhar Did you use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: The pdf is getting generated but there is no data inside it.

Comment: @LanceJava Yes i am using <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: @AlexK I haven't tried font extensions yet. If you have any guide related to chinese chars using Font Extensions then pls share.

Comment: @RaviShekhar You can look at this posts: [Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8985497/876298) & [iReport external font](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9256114/876298)